Tool to view the ipa application's source code?
What tool can I use to view the application's source code if I have an ipa file?
Are there different tools depending on the language the application is written in, e.g. Objective-C, Swift, Xamarin, Flutter, etc.?
I don't have a Macbook.
I only have Linux or Windows.
Thank you for any help.
I try to improve my mobile application security knowledge.

Compiled executables can not be decompiled to their original source code. You can only view the assembler code or decompile the assembler of functions code back into a higher level language like C - if you are lucky and the code is not too complex and the decompiler is working correctly. Common decompiler are Ghidra, IDA Pro, Hopper. Note that for app reversing https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com is more on-topic than SO.

Thank you for your answer @Robert . So the only way to analyze clear and readable code of an iOS application is to receive uncompiled code from the client?
But I guess companies don't share their code.

Don't forget open source projects. I would search GitHub and Gitlab for iOS open source apps and libraries in various languages.

Thank you @Robert.
I thought about it and came to the conclusion that I need to write a small vulnerable Android app. This is the best way to become a good mobile security specialist.
Can you recommend what language I should write such an application in (JAVA, Kotlin, etc.)?
Do you recommend a good tool with which to write a mobile application? (e.g. Eclipse)
Do you recommend any course (free or paid), where I could learn how to write Android app? I don't want to be a developer, I just want to understand what vulnerabilities in mobile apps.
I'm not interested in API vulnerabilities.

A quick internet search would have shown you that there is Android Studio for developing apps. And apps often look different for each used language, therefore if you want to learn the differences you have to develop one app in every language.
